# how to say"expect my self to be in such situation"

Tags: sentence-construction

Have I correctly written this?

Once he became mentally incapable ,he didn't expect to find himself to be sad, for instance in public.

Thanks

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the construction you used and how would you like it to be different? I'm afraid that without further details we can't address this question properly.

Comment: Why is this question off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine, but if you want a more smooth expression then consider the following:

1. Once he became mentally incapable, he didn't expect to find himself
   sad
2. Once he became mentally incapable, he didn't expect to be ( or become) sad.